# nginx makes own html folder/file

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, vagrant

I have just setup my virtual machine setup with vagrant.
The virtual machine config i configured on https://puphpet.com.

Everything is fine and works (I can ssh to the VM, ...). But I can't seem to connect to the right folder in my application.

My application is a Symfony 3.2 app, so the default connect folder and file are: /web/app.php (or /web/app_dev.php).

When I run vagrant, it automatically creates a html with index.html folder in the root folder of the shared folder (so in ./ ) although I have not setted it up that way.

I know it's just tweaking of the settings (I guess?), but I can't seem to get it working.

This is my config.yml:

```
vagrantfile:
target: local
vm:
    provider:
        local:
            box: puphpet/ubuntu1604-x64
            box_url: puphpet/ubuntu1604-x64
            box_version: '0'
            chosen_virtualizer: virtualbox
            virtualizers:
                virtualbox:
                    modifyvm:
                        natdnshostresolver1: false
                    showgui: 0
                vmware:
                    numvcpus: 1
                parallels:
                    linked_clone: 0
                    check_guest_tools: 0
                    update_guest_tools: 0
            machines:
                vflm_yo94xzj3amtb:
                    id: IDOFMACHINE
                    hostname: machine1.puphpet
                    network:
                        private_network: 192.168.56.101
                    memory: '512'
                    cpus: '1'
    provision:
        puppet:
            manifests_path: puphpet/puppet/manifests
            module_path:
                - puphpet/puppet/modules
                - puphpet/puppet/manifests
            options:
                - '--verbose'
                - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
    synced_folder:
        vflsf_4nfi36d4rw19:
            source: ./
            target: /var/www
            sync_type: nfs
            smb:
                smb_host: ''
                smb_username: ''
                smb_password: ''
                mount_options:
                    dir_mode: '0775'
                    file_mode: '0664'
            rsync:
                args:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--archive'
                    - '-z'
                exclude:
                    - .vagrant/
                    - .git/
                auto: 'true'
            owner: www-data
            group: www-data
    usable_port_range:
        start: 10200
        stop: 10500
    post_up_message: ''
ssh:
    host: 'false'
    port: 'false'
    private_key_path: 'false'
    username: vagrant
    guest_port: 'false'
    keep_alive: '1'
    forward_agent: 'false'
    forward_x11: 'false'
    shell: 'bash -l'
    insert_key: 'false'
vagrant:
    host: detect
proxy:
    http: ''
    https: ''
    ftp: ''
    no_proxy: ''
server:
    install: '1'
    packages:
        - vim
users_groups:
    install: '1'
    groups:
        - USERGROUP
    users:
        - USERNAME
locale:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        default_locale: en_US.UTF-8
        locales:
            - en_GB.UTF-8
            - en_US.UTF-8
        timezone: Europe/Brussels
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: {  }
cron:
    install: '1'
    jobs: {  }
nginx:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: present
        default_vhost: 1
        proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
        proxy_buffer_size: 128k
        proxy_connect_timeout: 600s
        proxy_send_timeout: 600s
        proxy_read_timeout: 600s
        names_hash_bucket_size: 128
    upstreams: {  }
    vhosts: {  }
    proxies: {  }
letsencrypt:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        email: ''
    domains: {  }
php:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '7.1'
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - xml
        pear: {  }
        pecl: {  }
    ini:
        display_errors: 'On'
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
        date.timezone: UTC
    fpm_ini:
        error_log: /var/log/php-fpm.log
    fpm_pools:
        phpfp_fo0v12pi60wc:
            ini:
                prefix: www
                listen: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                security.limit_extensions: .php
                user: www-user
                group: www-data
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
ruby:
    install: '1'
    versions:
        rv_3wwtzfmr5ph7:
            default: '1'
            bundler: '1'
            version: 2.3.1
            gems:
                - deep_merge@1.0.1
                - activesupport@4.2.6
                - vine@0.2
python:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
    versions: {  }
mysql:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '5.7'
        root_password: PASSWORD
        override_options: {  }
    adminer: 0
    users:
        mysqlnu_dhshopbnzmjt:
            name: DBNAME
            password: DBPASSWORD
    databases:
        mysqlnd_cgzy7ctnghxn:
            name: dbname
            sql: ''
    grants:
        mysqlng_176bhrghj78b:
            user: dbuser
            table: '*.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have any vhosts set up.

For example, here's the default Nginx section:

```
nginx:
install: '1'
settings:
    version: present
    default_vhost: 1
    proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
    proxy_buffer_size: 128k
    proxy_connect_timeout: 600s
    proxy_send_timeout: 600s
    proxy_read_timeout: 600s
    names_hash_bucket_size: 128
upstreams: {  }
vhosts:
    nxv_g7clf38t8tsy:
        server_name: awesome.dev
        server_aliases:
            - www.awesome.dev
        www_root: /var/www/awesome
        listen_port: '80'
        client_max_body_size: 1m
        ssl: '0'
        ssl_cert: ''
        ssl_key: ''
        ssl_port: '443'
        ssl_protocols: ''
        ssl_ciphers: ''
        rewrite_to_https: '1'
        spdy: '1'
        locations:
            nxvl_1anmyow0cd4b:
                www_root: ''
                location: /
                index_files:
                    - index.html
                    - index.htm
                    - index.php
                try_files:
                    - $uri
                    - $uri/
                    - /index.php$is_args$args
                fastcgi: ''
                fastcgi_index: ''
                fastcgi_split_path: ''
                proxy: ''
                proxy_redirect: ''
            nxvl_yhk6qxrhfjqr:
                www_root: ''
                location: '~ \.php$'
                try_files:
                    - $uri
                    - $uri/
                    - /index.php$is_args$args
                fastcgi: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                fastcgi_index: index.php
                fastcgi_split_path: '^(.+\.php)(/.*)$'
                fast_cgi_params_extra:
                    - 'SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename'
                    - 'APP_ENV dev'
                set:
                    - '$path_info $fastcgi_path_info'
                proxy: ''
                proxy_redirect: ''
proxies: {  }
```

Your config is missing the whole `vhosts:` block.

Recreate your config.